# Npm and angular give me problem about proxy after install and uninstall Fiddler

Tags: angular, windows, npm, proxy, fiddler

After I unistalled **Fiddler**, I cannot use **Angular** and **npm**, because I get some errors about proxy.

If I do an http call with angular I get this error:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request **** from
> localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8080/ (ECONNRESET)
> (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

If I try to install something using npm I get this one:

> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! syscall read
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\grtommason\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-20T21_14_42_846Z-debug-0.log

I set proxy and http-proxy in npm, I changed the registry in npm. I unistalled angular and unistalled npm. I reset network from windows. I deleted manually all the certificate that Fiddler creates, but nothing solves the problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You have to remove the proxy configuration just as the error message suggest. If a proxy is configured but not running all connections will fail. Cross-platform tools like npm doen't use Windows proxy config but have own configuration files. Read `npm help config` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even with an highspeed intetrnet and this Method Solve My Problem.
If you have installed Node.js then you already have the Node.js Command Prompt installed Run your command in that Command Prompt.